# Brass wire brush to clean plated fasteners?

Tags: cleaning, fastener

Almost always when working on vehicles you need to clean the threads of an old fastener, especially if you're re-applying loctite.

Using a bench grinder with a steel wire wheel works real good but the steel very quickly strips off the protective zinc or nickle plating on the fastener - the bolt looks clean and nice but not for long! Without the plating the raw steel will corrode super quickly.

Any advice on how to clean fasteners without damaging the protective coating? I've been using a brass wire brush, but not sure if that's ideal. Brass is technically a mix of zinc and copper, and copper is super soft, so I'm assuming it would be softer vs the electroplated zinc or nickle coating and won't damage it while still removing dried old loctite, rust, etc?

I know you can get a zinc plating set up to refresh the protective coating, but there is a ton of prep involved and would be far too time consuming for general vehicle work! I'm not restoring an antique to perfection, I just want to avoid doing damage to high quality OEM plated fasteners while doing general work.

Answer (score 3):

I personally use a brass wire wheel (just like your steel one, but made of brass) on my bench grinder. I use it to clean all of my fasteners before I put them back into use. This method has never given me any issue, however, I haven't worried about coatings on the fastener itself, so I cannot tell you if it will strip it or not. It seems to brighten all of the fasteners and definitely removes any dirt or corrosion. It is a heck of a lot better than trying to use a brush to do it, as it is faster and more complete.

**PS:** I've also used my brass wire wheel to clean *everything* off of intake/exhaust valves with absolutely *zero* marking/marring. Best cleaning solution I've ever found for getting them absolutely down to metal without worry of damage.

Comment: Same here, I use a brass wire wheel and it doesn't seem to harm fastener plating at all. Just make sure you're using pure brass, not a brass plated steel wire wheel, which will take the plating right off. You can use a magnet to check and confirm that it's pure brass and not brass plated steel.

Comment: @MTA - Very good observance towards brass plated steel wire ... something to definitely pay attention to.

Comment: Yes, many of the 'brass' wire wheels are actually steel wire that is brass coated. Why do they even do that? What's that particular wheel for?

I've not found any pure brass wire wheels for 8" bench grinders -> anyone have a recommended North American manufacturer?

Comment: @WaitButWhy - Check out McMaster-Carr (no affiliation) ... they have a very broad assortment and sizes of just about everything industrial, including wire wheel brushes.